# Explorer.exe refuses to start after upgrade Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

## The problem:

On boot, Windows will not start explorer.exe. My desktop is blank, the task switcher has a very basic style, I have no taskbar, etc. Attempting to start Explorer from Task Manager has no effect.

## What happened:

I've been putting this upgrade off for a while because I'm lazy. Maybe a month ago, I decided to upgrade. When I did, I logged into the current situation. I was able to revert to the old build, and I can still do that if I need to, but I want to get this fixed.

## Some info:

- I can run `explorer.exe -r` to open an Explorer window. I can open any other program perfectly fine.
- I have tried virus removal tools.
- I have tried using Tweaking.com's AIO Repair Tool.
- I have tried updating my graphic driver.
- I have researched this for about 2 hours straight with no luck.

Using WinDbg, I managed to get this:

```
Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Zacha\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\explorer.exe.8400.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 15063 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS Personal
15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sat Jul  1 17:05:24.000 2017 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:05:18.711
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:17.000
......................................................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(20d0.2ac8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14:
00007ffe`4da95f04 c3              ret
0:000> .ecxr
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=00000000004ee620 rcx=00000000004ee650
rdx=000000000010da10 rsi=00000000004d6ac8 rdi=00007ffe4447b708
rip=00000000004ee620 rsp=000000000010d9c8 rbp=000000000010eff8
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000007 r10=0000000000000000
r11=00007ffe4da9bf1b r12=000000000010f370 r13=0000000000000000
r14=00007ffe444a3000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
00000000`004ee620 a81d            test    al,1Dh
```

What caught my eye is: `ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14`. But I've researched this as well to no avail.

---

Is there anything else I can try? Of course, I can always fall back to the previous build, but I'd like to get the latest version working if I can.

Comment: Same behavior in safe mode?

Comment: Explorer actually works in Safe Mode @AndroidDev

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: run **!analyze -v** in windbg to see more details

Answer (score 2):

Well I thought everything was failing, and I'd just have to fall back to the old build. `sfc /scannow` found nothing, and I was giving up hope.

So I installed Visual Studio and opened the DMP file to get (I guess) a stacktrace. I noticed that `msvcrt.dll` was in the stacktrace and that it was on version 7, while the rest were version 10. Now, my instinct was misled, and version 7 is indeed the correct version, but this led me to search that DLL and try something I'd dismissed: DISM.

After I ran

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

I was able to start Explorer!

I didn't think this would work, and I'd just (stupidly) ignored it.

I'm going to VTC this as no-repro.

Comment: Sounds like you got a nice find there, so good job for getting resolved and sharing the solution. This is also a case where a full OS system image backup could have come into play for you as well I suppose.

Comment: @McDonald's well I could always just revert to the old build, but this time I wanted to get the new one working.